# is formtastic form only can used with ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can I use formtastic with a non-ActiveRecord model?

something like (seems not work):

```
= semantic_form_for(:non_active_record_model) do |v|
  -v.inputs do
    .field
    =v.input :start_date, :as=> :datepicker
    =v.input :end_date, :as => :datepicker
    =v.input :name
    ...


  -v.buttons do
    =v.save_or_cancel_button("save")
```

Answer (score 2):

It does work. you need to use semantic_fields_for instead of semantic_form_for.